# Prepared Statement Inner Join Cannot Pass Parameter by Reference

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, inner-join, fatal-error

I've been trying to figure this out for a good while now and I've searched for similar problems, but can't really find a solution.

I'm working on a game setup application and I'm having an issue with my prepared statement.

```
if ($stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT pack.id, COUNT(race.name) 
                                  FROM pack 
                                     INNER JOIN race ON pack.id = race.pack 
                                  WHERE pack.id = ? 
                                  GROUP BY race.pack")) {

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION["id"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($rsltID, rsltRaces);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $racesPack[$rsltID] = $rsltRaces;
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
```

this returns an error: "Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference".

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you try replacing `$stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION["id"]);` with `$sid = $_SESSION["id"]; $stmt->bind_param("s", $sid);`?

Comment: You've an error on the 4th line, there is a missing $ in front of the variable. It'll assume it's a constant which can't be passed by ref.

Comment: @temporalslide You have figured out my issue... I just came to that conclusion myself and went to post here. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your  `$stmt->bind_result($rsltID, rsltRaces);` is wrong. it should be `$stmt->bind_result($rsltID, $rsltRaces);`